# MYSQL - Counting with Clause

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

I'm working on a tchat room and all messages are stored in the same table "message".
What i want is to list distinct users and display new messages order by new message.

Here is my MYSQL Table 'message' :

Let say i'm the pseudo 'OLIVER' !

```
  id  | lu     | view_date   | pseudo   | destinataire    | message    | date        |
------+--------+-------------+----------+-----------------+------------+-------------+
 7181 | 0      | 0           | OLIVER   | WILLIAM         | HELLO      | 1418214808  +
 7183 | 0      | 0           | WILLIAM  | OLIVER          | HELLO      | 1418214808  +
 7184 | 0      | 0           | OLIVER   | WILLIAM         | HELLO      | 1418214808  +
 7184 | 1      | 1418214808  | OLIVER   | MIKE            | HELLO      | 1418214808  +
 7101 | 1      | 1418214808  | MIKE     | OLIVER          | HELLO      | 1418214808  +
 7186 | 0      | 0           | SUPERMAN | BATMAN          | HELLO      | 1418214808  +
 7187 | 0      | 0           | DONALD   | MICKEY          | HELLO      | 1418214808  +
 7188 | 0      | 0           | GREG     | OLIVER          | HELLO      | 1418214808  +
 7189 | 0      | 0           | GREG     | WILLIAM         | HELLO      | 1418214808  +             
 7189 | 0      | 0           | FUNKY    | OLIVER          | HELLO      | 1418214808  +             
 7189 | 1      | 1418214808  | BERNARD  | OLIVER          | HELLO      | 1418214808  +             
 7189 | 1      | 1418214808  | OLIVER   | BERNARD         | HELLO      | 1418214808  +             
 7188 | 0      | 0           | GREG     | OLIVER          | HELLO      | 1418214808  +
```

Results shouled display only records related to the pseudo 'OLIVER' for exemple :

```
pseudo   | total new Messages
---------+-------------------+
 GREG    | 2                  <-- 3 entry but only 2 new message lu field = 0
 WILLIAM | 1                  <-- 2 entry but only 1 new message lu field = 0
 FUNKY   | 1                  <-- 1 entry lu field = 0  
 MIKE    | 0                  <-- 1 entry lu field = 0  
 BERNARD | 0                  <-- 1 entry lu field = 0
```

# New (UNREAD) messages are handle with the field lu and the value = "0"

# Old (READ) messages are handle with the field lu and the value = "1"

My actual query counts all messages for all distinct users related to 'OLIVER' how can i count all new messages for all distinct users ?

```
SELECT data, SUM(cnt) AS cnt
FROM (
(
SELECT destinataire AS data, COUNT(id) AS cnt 
FROM message 
WHERE pseudo = '".$_SESSION['pseudo']."' 
GROUP BY data
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT pseudo AS data, COUNT(id) AS cnt 
FROM message 
WHERE destinataire = '".$_SESSION['pseudo']."' 
GROUP BY data
)
) pd 
GROUP BY data
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: I think "William"s count should be 2.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the logic you describe, I think this query does what you want:

```
SELECT destinataire, pseudo, SUM(lu = 0) AS cnt
FROM message
GROUP BY destinataire, pseudo
ORDER BY pseudo, cnt DESC;
```

You can also add a `where` clause to restrict the results to a single `destinataire`.